# Determine vertex coordinates of a triangle if length and angles of opposite are known

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Given a triangle such as this:
[image: Triangle]

Where $C$, $A$ and $B$ are cartesian coordinates and $a$, $b$, $c$ are the lengths of the sides.

I know that $$C = (b\cos\theta,\;b\sin\theta)$$
where $\theta$ is the angle at vertex $A$.

However, in my case, I do not know $b$, but I do know $c$ and the gradient at both $A$ and $B$.

How can I find $C$?

Answer (score 1):

The equation $C = (b\cos\theta,\;b\sin\theta)$ makes sense only if
the coordinates of $A$ are $(0,0)$, so I suppose $A = (0,0)$.

Then $B = (c,0)$.

From a point and the slope of a line, you can derive an equation
for the line. So you can easily find equations for lines $AC$ and $CB$.

From the equations of two lines you can find the coordinates of
their intersection.

That should be enough to solve the problem. But if the slope of $AC$ is
$\tan \alpha$ and the slope of $CB$ is $-\tan \beta$ 
(where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the positive angles at $A$ and $B$,
and the slope of $CB$ is negative indicating it slopes down to the right),
then the coordinates of $C=(c_x, c_y)$ can be found from the
relations

\begin{align}
c_y &= c_x \tan \alpha, \\
c_y &= (c - c_x)\tan \beta,
\end{align}

as you can confirm by dropping a perpendicular from $C$ to $AB$ and
labeling the lengths of the legs and angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$
of the two right triangles so drawn.